# Pandas dataframe: converting column of lists to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `hashtags` such that:

```
df['hashtags']
>>>
0                                                       NaN
1                                                       NaN
2                                               ['COVID19']
3                                               ['COVID19']
4                         ['CoronaVirusUpdates', 'COVID19']
                                ...                        
132596    ['coronacrise', 'covid19', 'JN', 'NãoÉSóUmNúme...
132597                                          ['covid19']
132598                                ['corona', 'covid19']
132599                                                  NaN
132600                                          ['covid19']
Name: hashtags, Length: 132601, dtype: object
```

I want to create a list containing all the lists' elements (except the `Nan`) of the column. 
 I have tried to make a list of lists by:

```
li = df['hashtags'].tolist()
```

But it's converting the lists into a string and end up with a list of strings.
For example:

```
li[:5]
>>> 
[nan, nan, "['COVID19']", "['COVID19']", "['CoronaVirusUpdates', 'COVID19']"]
```

My desired output for `li[:5]` is like:

```
['COVID19', 'COVID19', 'CoronaVirusUpdates', 'COVID19', 'coronavirus', 'covid19']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: @MichaelO. I need to make a list of lists first, that's where I am facing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is first remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), then convert list repr by `ast.literal_eval` to lists and flatten nested lists in list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hashtags':[np.nan, np.nan, 
                               "['COVID19']", "['COVID19']", 
                               "['CoronaVirusUpdates', 'COVID19']"]})

import ast

out = [y for x in df['hashtags'].dropna() for y in ast.literal_eval(x)]
print (out)
['COVID19', 'COVID19', 'CoronaVirusUpdates', 'COVID19']
```